# Formatting dates in C

Tags: c, date

I have some GPS string dates that look like:

```
 "181215" //11th Dec 2015
 "211115" //21st Nov 2015
```

I can work with this format but but when the day or month is one digit it looks like:

```
 "11215" //1st Dec 2015
 "8515" //8th May 2015
```

What's the best way to turn `8515` into `080515` in C?

I basically need to turn the string into 3 Integers, I'm doing it like this:

```
//date: 171115
char str[8];
sprintf(str, "%d", date);
char component[3];

sprintf(component,"%c%c",str[0],str[1]);
int day = strtof(component, NULL);

sprintf(component,"%c%c",str[2],str[3]);
int month = strtof(component, NULL);

sprintf(component,"%c%c",str[4],str[5]);
int year = strtof(component, NULL) + 2000;
```

Comment: What does  ` "1111" `  mean to you?

Comment: How can you tell whether 11215 is supposed to be 11th Feb 2015 or 1st Dec 2015?

Comment: How you can differentiate 11.1 and 1.11? They are all 11115

Comment: Without knowing if  `11215` is the 11th february or 1st december by additional information, it is impossible to do that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 1111 would be 1st Jan 2011

Comment: The string length could give a pointer to wether it is missing one leading zero or two

Comment: why don't you use time_t and epoch ( counting seconds since 1.1.1970 ) and covert it to date when you print it

Comment: @arc_lupus it's GPS date so it is always D M Y, the year is always 2 digits but the day and month could be wither 1 or 2 digits

Comment: If the month is always the current month, for instance, there is something to do. Otherwise, you never know, at it is mentioned above, if 11215 is december or february. Of course if there is initially a space between day and month ... that's easier!

Comment: Hurt the guy who made such ambiguous definitions. (Unless, of course, somewhere is defined if `11215` means 2015-02-11 or 2015-12-01, but even then, it is useful to have the format as simple as possible.) , You'll have to find a valid and unique definition. Only then you can start with e. g. differentiating between your cases according to the string length or so.

Comment: Find out if there is a rule that e. g. the day may only be shortened if the month isn't shortened or something like this.

Comment: "it's GPS date so it is always D M Y" Non sequitur. Someone made this (incomplete) transition, and you should find out how to remove the ambiguity in it.

Comment: `"181215" //11th Dec 2015` is confusing.  Surely that is the _18th_ of December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that gives a recognisable error output for ambiguous dates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* N.B. returns a pointer to static storage - not for production use */
/* Returns "??????" on failure */
const char *reformat(const char *s)
{
    static char buf[9];

    int d, m, y;                /* day, month, year */
    switch (strlen(s)) {
    case 6:
        return s;
    case 5:
        if (s[1] == '1' && s[2] <= '2') {
            /* second digit may be part of day or month */
            if (s[0] <= '2' || s[0] <= '3' && s[2] == '1')
                return "??????";              /* ambiguous string */
            /* 1-digit day, 2-digit month */
            sscanf(s, "%1d%2d%2d", &d, &m, &y);
        break;
        }
        /* 2-digit day; 1-digit month */
        sscanf(s, "%2d%1d%2d", &d, &m, &y);
        break;
    case 4:
        sscanf(s, "%1d%1d%2d", &d, &m, &y);
        sprintf(buf, "%02d%02d%02d", d, m, y);
        return buf;
    default:
        return "??????";              /* invalid input length */
    };
    sprintf(buf, "%02d%02d%02d", d, m, y);
    return buf;
}
```

And here's a test program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        printf("%6s -> %s\n", *argv, reformat(*argv));
    return 0;
}
```

On my test cases, it produces:

```
   111 -> ??????
  8515 -> 080515
181215 -> 181215
  1111 -> 010111
 11215 -> ??????
 31211 -> 031211
 29212 -> 290212
 21200 -> ??????
 21300 -> 210300
11111111 -> ??????
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
char str[8];
sprintf(str, "%d", date);
char corr_str[8];

switch (strlen(str)) {
  case 6: // easiest way:
    strcpy(corr_str, str);
    break:
  case 4:
    corr_str[0] = '0';
    corr_str[1] = str[0];
    corr_str[2] = '0';
    // corr_str[3] = str[1];
    // corr_str[4] = str[2];
    // corr_str[5] = str[3];
    strcpy(corr_str + 3, str + 1);
    break;
  case 5: // Well, what now? Is the day shortened or the month?
    // Here we assume the day is shortened, so 11215 is 2015-12-01.
    corr_str[0] = '0';
    strcpy(corr_str + 1, str);
    break;
    // Here we assume the month is shortened, so 11215 is 2015-02-11.
    strcpy(corr_str, str);
    corr_str[2] = '0';
    strcpy(corr_str + 3, str + 2);
    break;
```

and then proceed as you did before.

Comment: You might also choose to log a warning if it's a 5-digit string and it matches one of the ambiguous dates `[12]1[12]..` or `311..` (in regexp syntax).

Comment: @TobySpeight Right. I suppose it *is* defined somewhere, but the OP doesn't want to tell us. Either way could be appropriate then...